# How to append br tag to Outlook composer body via setAsync?

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm writing an Outlook Add-in using API 1.4 and attempting to append a `br` tag to an Outlook 2016 composer body.

However, as soon as one starts typing Outlook reformats the document and strips the element.

The following is the implementation, which is called on a 1s polling interval—there isn't a better way to observe the DOM as far as I can tell.

```js
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
  Office.CoercionType.Html, {
    asyncContext: "Body"
  },
  function(asyncResult) {
    // DOMParser
    var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("document");
    doc.documentElement.innerHtml = asyncResult.value;

    // Append <br> if not found
    var isModified = false;
    var $html = $(doc.documentElement);
    var $body = $html.find("body"); 
    if (!!$body.find("br[id*='unique-identifier']").length) {
      $body.append("<br id='unique-identifier'>");
      isModified = true;
    }

    // Set if <br> was not found
    if (isModified) {
      Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(
        $body.html(), {
          coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html
        }
        function(asyncResult) {}
      )
    }
  }
);
```

Subsequent getAsync shows the `br` tag until you start typing, then it gets removed and setAsync is called again. This is an annoyance since setAsync causes the cursor to jump to the beginning of the composer and interferes with a user typing fluidly. I'm unable to use prepend or setSelectedDataAsync in this case due to the nature of the `br` tag.

I assume the reformatting happens through conversion from plain HTML to a Word Doc based on the asyncResult value, but I don't know how to account for this.

NB: This is also different from OWA which doesn't convert between Word Doc and HTML but does prefix the `id` and other attributes like `class` with `x_` and causes the cursor to jump around.

Comment: Did you try to mimic your <br /> tag with div or span? Is this going to be removed as well: "<div id='your_id' style='clear:both'>&nbsp;</div>"?

Comment: The div with the styling and &nbsp; works, though an empty div does not. Are there certain limitations to what is considered "valid" in Outlook?

Comment: The [documentation](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Body.html) doesn't limit you to use any HTML tags. The issue with empty tags (stand alone br or empty div) is just internal Outlook optimization of the body content. When you would use some values, the tags will not be stripped. At least you have your issue solved, are you?

Comment: One is effectively limited to what one may set by Outlook "optimizations". OWA modifies minor things to the body like attributes, but Outlook completely reformats HTML and styling. If I set the body with HTML, the formatting should reflect what I've asked to set, not what Outlook optimizes to. This may be a small way to circumvent Outlook, but it's not a catch-all.

Answer (score 0):

I created a prototype to show br element in email body. You can try the below code:

```
Office.initialize = function () {   
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync("<span>begin</span><br id='unique-identifier' /><span>end</span>",  {coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html});
    }
}
```

After running, there is a br between begin and end.
Visit https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Body.html#setAsync to find more information.